# Can del_timer return while its handler is running?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel

I'm looking at some Linux kernel module code that starts and stops timers using [add_timer](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c?v=3.4#L893) and [del_timer](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c?v=3.4#L945).

Sometimes, the implementation goes on to delete the timer "object" (the [struct timer_list](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/timer.h?v=3.4#L12)) right after calling del_timer.

I'd like to find out is if this is safe.  Note that this is a uniprocessor implementation, with SMP disabled (which would mandate the use of [del_timer_sync](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c?v=3.4#L1043) instead).

The del_timer_sync implementation checks if the timer is being handled anywhere right now, but del_timer does not.  On a UP system, is it possible to have the timer being handled without del_timer knowing, i.e. the timer has been removed from the pending timers list and is being handled?

Comment: Just use `del_timer_sync()`, that way when you or the next person decides they actually would like to use this code on an SMP system it won't break :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UP makes things quite a bit simpler, but I think the answer is still "it depends."

If you are doing `del_timer` in process context, then on UP I think you are safe in assuming the timer is not running anywhere after that returns: the timers are removed from the pending lists and run from the timer interrupt, and if that interrupt starts, it will run to completion before allowing the process context code to continue.

However, if you are in interrupt context, then your interrupt might have interrupted the timer interrupt, and so the timer might be in the middle of being run.